# javascript preloader be able to detect functions without reference, jshint-loader does not the job

Tags: javascript, jshint

I have this file: greetings.js

```
 function greetings ()  {
    return {
        hello: function  () {

            return 'hello';
        },
        bye: function  () {
            lostfunction.write ('this is function does not exists');
            return 'bye';
        }

    };
}

 module.exports = greetings;
```

in the bye function there is a not defined  object or function: "lostfunction", but Jshint does not display warnings or errors; just in the browser console i get:

Uncaught ReferenceError: lostfunction is not defined

All loaders are not able to show this type of error ?